# How do I host a subdomain at Hostgator when the main site is currently hosted with 000webhost?

Tags: web-hosting, subdomain

I am currently using 000webhost.com host.  I create a subdomain there. I want to use that subdomain at hostgator. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Have you tried contacting them? why consider a domain from a company that you don't feel is approachable.

Comment: Will they tell regarding this issue,

Comment: Considering its their domain... yes.

Answer (score 1):

You change the A record for the subdomain (only) to point to the IP address of hostgator.  At hostgator you set up the subdomain in their system.

The downsides of hostgator is for another question.

Comment: Yup.  

And just to clarify a bit, you create/change the subdomain in 000webhost's control panel